# android customize spinner

Tags: android, xml, textview

I want to know if is possible to customize a textview.
I want to look like a spinner
So i define an xml to be used as a layout background
In this xml i put

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
    />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
    />
    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
    />
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"
    />
    <size
        android:height="70dip"
    />
</shape>
<bitmap 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon" 
    android:gravity="right" />
```

but doesn't work
SO i want to have something like in css, define round corners, padding, color and add a icon as a background on the right. This icon is a arrow that look like a spinner arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your TextView in XML like this.

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="This looks like a spinner now!"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
    />
```

Comment: No, i still want to customize the spinner layout. I want to change the radius, the and also the arrow of spinner. So my question is if i can combine the <shape> and <bitmap> in the same xml layout.